Google Sign-in not working on Android's Closed Testing Release
I recently published a closed testing release on Google Play Console, but me and all other testers have reported that they are unable to sign in using Google Sign-In.
Context:
I am developing the app using Flutter and Firebase Authentication. Here’s an overview of what I did for both the development and production environments:

Dev Environment:


Generated a SHA-1 and SHA-256 for the development keystore.
Added these to the Firebase dev project.
Everything works fine in the dev environment—no issues with Google Sign-In.


Prod Environment:


Created a separate Firebase project for production.
Created a new keystore for the production environment.
Added the SHA-1 and SHA-256 from the production keystore to the Firebase prod project and Google Cloud Console to generate the necessary OAuth 2.0 Client IDs.
In my build.gradle, I differentiate between dev and prod environments as follows:


    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }



I switch between two google-services.json files: one for dev and one for prod, depending on the branch.

Issue:
Before publishing to Google Play's closed testing, I tested the production environment, and Google Sign-In was working without issues.

For testing, I used the following command to generate the APK for release:

flutter build apk --release --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --obfuscate --split-debug-info=./build/reports


For Google Play closed testing, I built an AAB from the same prod branch, but Google Sign-In is not working. When I connected my device and checked the logcat, I found this error when attempting to use Google Sign-In:

[firebase_auth/invalid-credential] access_token audience is not for this project

Questions:

Could this issue be related to the fact that it is a closed testing release on Google Play?
Is this problem caused by using AAB instead of APK?
Am I missing something in the configuration between Firebase, Google Play Console, or the OAuth client setup?
Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance for your help!
EDIT:
This question was marked as duplicate but it is not, what i am facing is different than the other issue, i tried doing what was mentioned in this post:
access_token audience is not for this project
but i do not have the .android folder and i am already using two different builds, one for debug and one for prod.

When uploading AAB, likely app-signing is enabled; this requires another key's SHA-256 hash. The local "release key" becomes the "upload key" and the package is being singed with a Google-managed "app-signing key".
